# Why does Java test coverage report uncovered classes when using a Builder pattern

Tags: java, inner-classes, test-coverage, builder-pattern

I added a Builder pattern to several complex classes and when I ran coverage on my tests, all of the classes that use the Builder pattern now report that there is an uncovered class in the testing.

Here is a simplified example:

```
public class CoverageWithBuilder {

    public int fInt;

    public static class Builder {
        public Integer fInteger = null;

        public Builder setInt(int i) {
            fInteger = i;
            return this;
        }

        public CoverageWithBuilder build() {
            if (fInteger == null)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Oops");

            return new CoverageWithBuilder(fInteger);
        }

    }

    private CoverageWithBuilder(int i) {
        fInt = i;
    }

    public int getInt() {
        return fInt;
    }
}
```

And here's the test:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class CoverageWithBuilderTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        CoverageWithBuilder t = new CoverageWithBuilder.Builder().setInt(9).build();
        assertEquals(9, t.getInt());
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void test2() {
        new CoverageWithBuilder.Builder().build();
    }
}
```

Coverage (using IntelliJ Idea with any of the coverage tool options - IntelliJ, Emma, JaCoCo) reports only partial class coverage:

```
CoverageWithBuilder .... 66% (2/3) . 100% (6/6) . 100% (12/12)
```

What is this third class of which the coverage tools speak?

Comment: If you look at your JaCoCo report, it can show you line-by-line coverage status; might help.

Comment: Since your constructor is private, this can result in an extra class being created to allow access. I suggest trying to make the constructor package local.

Comment: All lines are covered - that's in the summary above, and also in the IntelliJ view.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - Ding Ding Ding Ding Ding Ding Ding - Making the constructor package local gets rid of the extra class. Why is a hidden class created?

Comment: The JVM doesn't support accessing a private member in another class. Java does through adding generated code and methods like `access$000` but the JVM doesn't.